# Finding a minimum date before another date

Tags: sql, netezza

Let's say I have two tables. One is a table with information about customer service inquiries, which contains information about the customer and the time the inquiry was placed. The customer's information (in this case, the ID) is saved for all future inquiries.

```
CUST_ID     INQUIRY_ID      INQUIRY_DATE
001         34              2015-05-03 08:15
001         36              2015-05-05 13:12
002         39              2015-05-10 18:43
003         42              2015-05-12 14:58
003         46              2015-05-14 07:27
001         50              2015-05-18 19:06
003         55              2015-05-20 11:40
```

The other table contains information about the resolution dates for all customer inquiries.

```
CUST_ID      RESOLVED_DATE
001          2015-05-06 12:54
002          2015-05-11 08:09
003          2015-05-14 19:37
001          2015-05-19 16:12
003          2015-05-22 08:40
```

The resolution table doesn't have a key to link to the inquiry table other than the CUST_ID, so in order to calculate the time to resolution, I want to determine the minimum inquiry date before the resolution for EACH resolution date. The resulting table would look like this:

```
CUST_ID     FIRST_INQUIRY        RESOLVED_DT
001         2015-05-03 08:15     2015-05-06 12:54
001         2015-05-18 19:06     2015-05-19 16:12
002         2015-05-10 18:43     2015-05-11 08:09
003         2015-05-12 14:58     2015-05-14 19:37
003         2015-05-20 11:40     2015-05-22 08:40
```

At first I just went with min(case when INQUIRY_DATE < RESOLVED_DT), but for people like customers 001 and 003 who have multiple inquiries across different dates, the query would just return the first ever inquiry date, not the first since the last inquiry. Does anyone know how to do this? I'm using Netezza.

Comment: The path to least resistance would be to give a key to the resolution table.

Comment: Agreed, but unfortunately I don't have that power.

Comment: I gave you a response below.  Please let me know if this meets your needs.

Comment: What if inquiries didn't have a resolution? In case you didn't have resolution date `2015-05-06 12:54` then what is your expected output? And what if you didn't have res date `2015-05-11 08:09`?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach And what about duplicates, etc.  There are so many pitfalls here.

Comment: I think you mean 'minimum *after*', which makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a subquery for each table (`inquries` and `resolutions`) which numbers the transaction for each `CUST_ID` using the date.  Then, the two subqueries can be joined together using this ordered index column along with the `CUST_ID`.

I also used the `INQUIRY_ID` in the `inquiries` table to break a tie, should it occur.  There is not way to break a tie in the `resolutions` table for a given customer and date based on the data you showed us.

```
SELECT t1.CUST_ID, t1.INQUIRY_ID AS FIRST_INQUIRY, t2.RESOLVED_DATE AS RESOLVED_DT
FROM
(
    SELECT CUST_ID, INQUIRY_ID, INQUIRY_DATE,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
         FROM inquiries
         WHERE CUST_ID = t.CUST_ID AND INQUIRY_DATE <= t.INQUIRY_DATE
             AND INQUIRY_ID < t.INQUIRY_ID) AS index
    FROM inquiries AS t
) AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CUST_ID, RESOLVED_DATE,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
         FROM resolutions
         WHERE CUST_ID = t.CUST_ID AND RESOLVED_DATE < t.RESOLVED_DATE) AS index
    FROM resolutions t
) AS t2
    ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID AND t1.index = t2.index
```

Here are what the subquery tables look like:

**inquiries:**

```
CUST_ID     INQUIRY_ID      INQUIRY_DATE         index
001         34              2015-05-03 08:15     1
001         36              2015-05-05 13:12     2
002         39              2015-05-10 18:43     1
003         42              2015-05-12 14:58     1
003         46              2015-05-14 07:27     2
001         50              2015-05-18 19:06     3
003         55              2015-05-20 11:40     3
```

**resolutions:**

```
CUST_ID      RESOLVED_DATE        index
001          2015-05-06 12:54     1
002          2015-05-11 08:09     1
003          2015-05-14 19:37     1
001          2015-05-19 16:12     2
003          2015-05-22 08:40     2
```

Note that this solution is not robust to missing data, e.g. there is an inquiry which was not closed, or the resolution was never recorded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try it out. The missing data is not a concern, I'm only concerned with existing resolution dates.

Comment: If this be a comment, then I cannot imagine the length of an answer :-)

Comment: Ha, it's a bit longer than a comment, that's true, my apologies. I'm really looking at the code for the first time today, wouldn't this link the 5/14 inquiry to the 5/22 resolution for customer 003? (The 5/20 inquiry should be linked instead).

Comment: I gave the caviat that my answer will only work if you have no missing data (alternatively every transaction appears with exactly one inquiry and resolution).